# File I/O inside file which is created

Tags: c++, c

```
for(c='A'; c<='Z'; ++c)
{
     p = fopen("D:\\DriveName.txt", "w+"); 
     fseek( fp, filepointer , SEEK_SET );
     fputs(buffer,fp); 
     fclose(fp); 
     ++filepointer;
}
```

Whenever one loop passes further previous loop letter getting erased but pointer getting forward. help me out why its happening

Comment: you are reopening the file inside the loop. open the file prior to entering the loop or open the file with append mode.

Comment: I want to add letter evrytime loops goes by.... in another way how it can be possible

Comment: @VivekSingh 911 just told you

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
p = fopen("D:\\DriveName.txt", "w"); 
for(c='A'; c<='Z'; ++c)
{
    fputs(buffer,fp); 
}
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're overdoing it. fputs() is for writing C strings and you want to write a character at a time. fprintf() might be a better choice. Try this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("D:\\DriveName.txt", "w"); 
char c;

for (c='A'; c<='Z'; ++c)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%c",c );
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Well, we don't know if that's what the OP wants to do, maybe `buffer` contains something else. Also, I think `fputc` would be better for printing a single character to a `FILE*`.

Comment: Also, `w+` should be used instead of `w` as your current code would overwrite the file each time.

Comment: True, it's not clear what original intention was.

Comment: @Prerak `w+` is not for appending, `a` is. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/